# Virtus and booleans conversion

Tags: ruby, virtus

I'm using Virtus gem and trying to autocast Strings to Booleans, but without success...
If you can see what's wrong with this code...

```
Virtus.coercer do |config|
  config.string.boolean_map = { 'true' => true, 'false' => false }
end

class BookingWizard
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :know_doctor, Boolean, default: false
end

1.9.3 (main):0 > b = BookingWizard.new
=> #<BookingWizard:0x007fea748bf338
 @know_doctor=false>
1.9.3 (main):0 > b.know_doctor = "true"
=> "true"
1.9.3 (main):0 > b.know_doctor
=> "true"
1.9.3 (main):0 > b.know_doctor.class
=> String
1.9.3 (main):0 > Virtus.coercer[String].to_boolean("true")
=> true
```

Comment: The boolean_map is transposed.  I think you want `{'true' => true, 'false' => false}`

Comment: I didn't get your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnBalestracci I've updated the code with the inverted map, it still does not work :(

Comment: OK that was because of a mongoid bug : https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2648

Comment: @NicolasBlanco did you get autocasting from Strings to Booleans to work?  I followed the virtus documentation at https://github.com/solnic/virtus#building-modules-with-custom-configuration , but came across the same issue you had.

Comment: @NicolasBlanco the github issue you linked does not exist anymore. Are you having the same issue still?

Comment: @EricC I suggest that is you are having the same issue, first post an issue on Github. If no luck, then ask a question yourself, simply linking to this one for reference. :-)

Comment: The comments seem to indicate that this problem is solved, so I'll vote to close as "not reproducible".  @NicolasBlanco, if I am in error, let me know and we'll re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Axiom::Types::Boolean` instead of `Boolean` in case you already have a `Boolean` class defined.

```
class BookingWizard
  include Virtus

  attribute :know_doctor, Axiom::Types::Boolean, default: false
end
```

If this works you probably have a `::Boolean` class which is being found before the Virtus one. Use `show-source Boolean` in [pry](https://pryrepl.org) to find your `Boolean` class.